Counting odd integers in a consecutive sequence divisible by a given prime
For any integer $a, n > 1$, let $O_p(a,a+n)$ be the count of $i$ such that $a < i < a+n$, $i$ is odd, and $p | i$ where $p$ is any odd prime.
Does it follow that for any such $p, a, n >1$, that $O_p(1,1+n) \ge O_p(a,a+n)$?
This seems intuitive to me since if any consecutive sequence of $n$ integers contained 1 more integer divisible by $p$, if the count of odd integers divisible by $p$ matched before including that extra integer, it would still match afterwards since that extra integer would necessarily be even (otherwise, the count wouldn't have matched previous to including this integer in the count).

Why would you think this?  If $p>1+n$, the left hand is $0$, but the right hand could be positive.

If I understand the problem correctly, the answer seems to be no, because $1$ is relatively far away from an odd multiple of a prime.
For example: (With $p=7$, $a=6$, $n=19$):
$O_7(1,1+19)=1$ ($7$ is the only odd multiple of $7$ from $1$ to $20$). On the other hand, $O_7(6,6+19)=2$ (counting $7$ and $21$ as odd multiples of $7$ in the given interval).
